# Autodesk Forge GetBulkProperties2

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge

I'm currently trying to `viewer.model.getBulkProperties2()` because I need the externalIds of the model. I've been using a loop with `getProperties()` to get the externalId but whenever I try it with very large NWDs firefox / chrome crashes.

The thing is, even if I specify in the options object that I need the external ids with `needsExternalId:true`, the function is not returning them. This is the affected portion of my code :

```
viewer.model.getBulkProperties2(dbids,{propFilter:params,needsExternalId:true,ignoreHidden:false,categoryFilter:null},(res)=>{
    console.log(res)
});
```

The property I'm using is just Name, and this is the returned `res` variable:

```
[
    {
        "dbId": 2,
        "properties": [
            {
                "displayName": "Nombre",
                "displayValue": "Nivel 1",
                "displayCategory": "Datos de identidad",
                "attributeName": "Name",
                "type": 20,
                "units": "",
                "hidden": false,
                "precision": 0
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "dbId": 3,
        "properties": [
            {
                "displayName": "Nombre",
                "displayValue": "Nivel 2",
                "displayCategory": "Datos de identidad",
                "attributeName": "Name",
                "type": 20,
                "units": "",
                "hidden": false,
                "precision": 0
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Am I messing anything up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Sebastian's answer:

In order to retrieve external IDs for a list of objects in bulk, you'll need to do both:

1. Set the `options.needsExternalId` property to true (the table of external IDs can be quite large and therefore is excluded by default; setting this flag will ensure that the table is loaded)
2. Include `externalId` in the list of properties to retrieve (in the `options.propFilter` array)

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I just found out that you need to specify the `externalId` as a property to get it.